# Swift3: Openweather API returns nil and API errors

Tags: json, swift, swift3, openweathermap

I'm trying to run an app that allows you to use a search bar and it'll return just temp, city, and conditions. When I run it I get a nil return on the temp and a 'Code: 401 API not valid' error. However, both codes I've tried should be working. I'm probably trying to take the wrong data from OpenWeather but I can't seem to find out where or how to fix it - there are no other errors that appear.

I'm trying to combine two tutorials/guides on this topic, but one uses a different API & the other is in Swift2.

Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var citySearchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var conditionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!

    var temp: Int!
    var condition: String!
    var city: String!
    let apiID:String = "d7817e07565a0019c5e7851a59eeca73"

    var exists: Bool = true
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        citySearchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(citySearchBar.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_"))&appid=\(apiID))")!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                do {

                    let weatherData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
                        with: data!,
                        options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

                    let weather = weatherData

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.cityLabel.text = self.city
                        self.tempLabel.text = "\((self.temp))°"
                        self.conditionLabel.text = weather.description
                        }

                } catch let jsonError {
                    print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
                }  }  }

        task.resume()
    }  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the value for `temp` is a `Double` not an `Int`

```
var temp = 0.0
```

Second of all you don't set `temp` in the code. The value for `temp` is in the dictionary `main` in `weatherData`

```
if let main = weatherData["main"] as? [String:Any],
   let tempValue = main["temp"] as? Double {
       self.temp = tempValue
       print(tempValue)
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought that it was already set up in weatherData. Good to know.

Comment: As always, please read the JSON output. It's very easy. `[]` represent arrays, `{}` represent dictionaries